# GDB giving weird errors

Tags: c++, macos, gdb

I run my gdb program like so:

```
(gdb) r < err.in
```

And get the following warnings:

```
Starting program: /Users/prikshetsharma/Downloads/parser/parse < err.in                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[New Thread 0x1003 of process 39841]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[New Thread 0x1103 of process 39841]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[New Thread 0x1503 of process 39841]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bsd.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                               
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/darwin_vers.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                       
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/dirstat.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                           
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/dirstat_collection.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/err.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                               
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/exception.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                         
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/init.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                              
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mach.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                              
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/stdio.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                             
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/stdlib.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                            
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/string.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.                                                                                            
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/variant.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
```

What are these warnings and how to get rid of them? How to get these files and directories?

Comment: *`can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.`* - have you checked if the listed files or directories exist?

Comment: @JonnyHenly they don't. How does one get them?

Comment: Did you build your program with symbols / debug mode? (The `-g` option when compiling and linking.)

Comment: Yes, I compiled it with the -g option.

Answer (score 0):

> What are these warnings

The `libsystem_darwin.dylib` was built with `-fsplit-dwarf` or an equivalent option. That option keeps most of the debug info in the object file(s), and leaves a reference to the `.o` file in the `.dylib` so debugger can find the original `.o` and load debug info from it.

This makes the `.dylib` much smaller, while still allowing full access to debug info.

> how to get rid of them?

You could use `strip libsystem_darwin.dylib` (or MacOS equivalent -- I am not sure `strip` exists) to get rid of the debug references. Or just ignore them.